# Python Docx Module merges tables when added subsequently to document

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I'm using the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) module and python 3.9.0 to create word docx files with python. The problem I have is the following:

A) I defined a [table style](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html) named `my_table_style`

B) I open my template, add one table of that style to my document object and then I store the created file with the following code:

```
import os
from docx import Document

template_path = os.path.realpath(__file__).replace("test.py","template.docx")
my_file = Document(template_path)

my_file.add_table(1,1,style="my_table_style").rows[-1].cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run("hello")

my_file.save(template_path.replace("template.docx","test.docx"))
```

When I now open test.docx, it's all good, there's one table with one row saying "hello".

NOW, when I use this syntax to create two of these tables:

```
import os
from docx import Document

template_path = os.path.realpath(__file__).replace("test.py","template.docx")
my_file = Document(template_path)

my_file.add_table(1,1,style="my_table_style").rows[-1].cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run("hello")
my_file.add_table(1,1,style="my_table_style").rows[-1].cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run("hello")

my_file.save(template_path.replace("template.docx","test.docx"))
```

Instead of getting two tables, each with one row saying "hello", I get one single table with two rows, each saying "hello". The formatting is however correct, according to `my_table_style`, so it seems that python-docx merges two subsequently added tables of the same table style. Is this normal behavior? How can I avoid that?

Cheers!

HINTS:

When I use `print(len(my_file.tables))` to print the amount of tables present in my_file, I actually get "2"! Also, when I change the style used in the second `add_table` line it works all good, so this seems to be related to the fact of using the same style. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I would start by simplifying things as much as possible to narrow the field of possibilities. Start by getting rid of the path replacement. You can open a file as much as you want without changing the file on disk, as long as you save to a different name. How about opening with `Document("template.docx")` and saving with `document.save("test.docx")`. Also you should say more about how you created the table style and show any code if that's how you did it. Also see if you can do what you want by hand in Word to narrow it down to the style or `python-docx`.

Comment: @scanny cheers but I needed to specify the path + replacements, to make this script work as a program wherever you place it, and store the files the program will generate always in the same relative folders (the path replacements presented in my script above obviously don't correspond to the path switches I make in my real script..). Anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out, it seems to be default behaviour by Word to do what's described above. I manually [created a table style](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/table-templates-microsoft-word) `my_custom_style` in the `template.docx` file where I customized the table border lines etc. to have the format I want to have as if I would have two tables.
Instead of then using two `add_table()` statements, I used

```
new_table = my_file.add_table(1,1,style = "my_custom_style")
first_row = new_table.rows[-1]
second_row = new_table.add_row()
```

(you can actually access table styles defined in your template via python-docx, simply by using the table style name you used to manually create your table style in your word template file used to open your `Document` object. Just make sure you tick the "add this table style to the word template" option upon saving the style in Word and it should all work). Everything working now.